# Google Cloud fails to deploy app with message "No deployable artifacts were found. Unable to proceed."

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, gcloud

I am trying to deploy a java based web application to Google Cloud and when I use the gcloud CLI command `gcloud app deploy` as the documentation suggests I receive an error. Here is the relavent part of the error log:

```
Step #0: Pulling image: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/java/runtime-builder@sha256:29e14b9a764601f35d88b40fdbf1d2191c2df773d4e788575a3663fa2537bbb1
Step #0: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/java/runtime-builder@sha256:29e14b9a764601f35d88b40fdbf1d2191c2df773d4e788575a3663fa2537bbb1: Pulling from gcp-runtimes/java/runtime-builder
Step #0: Digest: sha256:29e14b9a764601f35d88b40fdbf1d2191c2df773d4e788575a3663fa2537bbb1
Step #0: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/java/runtime-builder@sha256:29e14b9a764601f35d88b40fdbf1d2191c2df773d4e788575a3663fa2537bbb1
Step #0: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/java/runtime-builder@sha256:29e14b9a764601f35d88b40fdbf1d2191c2df773d4e788575a3663fa2537bbb1
Step #0: Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.exception.ArtifactNotFoundException: No deployable artifacts were found. Unable to proceed.
Step #0:    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.buildsteps.PrebuiltRuntimeImageBuildStep.getArtifact(PrebuiltRuntimeImageBuildStep.java:77)
Step #0:    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.buildsteps.RuntimeImageBuildStep.run(RuntimeImageBuildStep.java:50)
Step #0:    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.BuildPipelineConfigurator.generateDockerResources(BuildPipelineConfigurator.java:104)
Step #0:    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.Application.main(Application.java:147)
Finished Step #0
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/java/runtime-builder@sha256:29e14b9a764601f35d88b40fdbf1d2191c2df773d4e788575a3663fa2537bbb1" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

The key part I believe is in the Exception stacktrace: `Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.exception.ArtifactNotFoundException: No deployable artifacts were found. Unable to proceed.`. There is no further explanation and I cannot find documentation on why this happens. I suspect it may be related to my build. The `mvn clean package` command does produce the jar file in the `target` directory. Below is my `pom.xml` and `app.yaml`. If other info is needed let me know. Since this issue is so unfamiliar to me I cannot think of what else may be needed.

`pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>chess</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>chess</name>
    <description>Lite chess UI using Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>
                ${project.build.directory}/appengine-staging
              </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`app.yaml`

```
runtime: java
env: flex
```

Note: about the `env: standard` I got errors about Java 6 not being supported. Go figure. I was just playing around with the config to see if it would change anything.

Comment: Can you try the `mvn clean package appengine:deploy` instead of `gcloud app deploy` when deploying your application?

Comment: I tried that. I get this error: ```appengine:run is only available for appengine-web.xml based projects, the service defined in: /home/<name>/ChessLive/target/chess-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT cannot be run by the dev appserver.```. What is the difference from using ```gcloud deploy``` and ```appengine:run```?

Comment: I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your `pox.xml` you want to use `java11` runtime:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
```

**App Engine Flexible**

As of now, the `java11` runtime is not supported in App Engine Flexible but its achievable using [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/about-custom-runtimes) and `Dockerfile`. You can use this sample [setup](https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine/c/iuud_jOCGpk) as a reference to have this kind of runtime environment.

**App Engine Standard**

`java11` runtime is supported in [App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/runtime) by declaring `java11` in `app.yaml`, example:

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: java11
```

**Application Deployment**

You should use `mvn clean package appengine:deploy` command if you are using Maven plugin in order to [deploy your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/quickstart#deploy_and_run_hello_world_on_app_engine) properly in App Engine and to avoid this kind of error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.exception.ArtifactNotFoundException: No deployable artifacts were found. Unable to proceed.

The difference of `gcloud app deploy` and `mvn appengine:deploy` is the `gcloud app deploy` is the command to deploy your app in App Engine using `gcloud` tools where `mvn appengine:deploy` is using Maven plugin.